# Google Tag Manager with Firebase crash iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager with Firebase in my app.

Here is my code that log screens and events :

```
import FirebaseAnalytics
import Foundation

public class AnalyticManager {
    public static func logScreen(_ name: String, className: String?) {
        Analytics.setScreenName(name, screenClass: className)
        Analytics.logEvent("open_screen", parameters: ["screenName": name])
    }
}
```

When I launch my app, I'm getting this crash :

```
2020-04-29 17:05:52.189148+0000 MyApp[15962:354528] -[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000033a500
2020-04-29 17:05:52.191676+0000 MyApp[15962:354528] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000033a500'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011719cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001170089b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001171bdc34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001171a190c ___forwarding___ + 1436
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001171a3bf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MyApp              0x000000010f9f597f -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueDispatch:] + 385
    6   MyApp              0x000000010f9f57e4 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueModel:] + 125
    7   Foundation                          0x0000000114543f42 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 209
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000117100eb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000117100ddc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001171005b4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001170fb1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 974
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001170faac4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    13  Foundation                          0x000000011452dd71 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 211
    14  Foundation                          0x000000011452df85 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
    15  MyApp              0x000000010f9e30b8 +[GAI threadMain:] + 62
    16  Foundation                          0x0000000114543aeb __NSThread__start__ + 1047
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff51b3b109 _pthread_start + 148
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff51b36b8b thread_start + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

When I use version 6.0 of Google Tag Manager the app doesn't crash, but I can't use it cause I need some features of Firebase that require latests version of Firebase that is not compatible with Google Tag Manager 6.0

How can I get rid of that crash ? thanks you in advance.

Comment: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/33231791?hl=en

Comment: I don’t see any answer about the issue in that link

Comment: Agreed, but that looks like a recommended place to get help for Tag Manager questions from https://support.google.com/tagmanager/community?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution for who have the same issue, remove "_" from the name of event, so I just replaced this line :

```
Analytics.logEvent("open_screen", parameters: ["screenName": name])
```

with:

```
Analytics.logEvent("openScreen", parameters: ["screenName": name])
```

and it worked.